# Simple question - Can i Flag a Tag?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Can i Flag a Tag?
What if there is an unnecessary tag created for advertising some product?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just add to Al's answer that if the tag is inappropriate but not spam or offensive — e.g., something off-topic like [marketing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) — it may be better to make a post here on Meta and see what people think.  Marketing might be obviously off-topic, but often it's less clear and there might be several alternative actions to discuss.  See the questions here tagged [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) to get a better idea of this.

Answer (score 7):

Just flag a post that it's on and use the "other" option to explain what's going on.